# How to setup data with n observations of m variables to perform FDA with scikit-fda

Tags: python, scikit-learn

What I'm trying to do is dimensionality reduction of a set of m log files containing n time-related signals. They are all physical signals so they are all related to time t.

I don't know how to treat this with scikit-fda and I don't know if it's possible to use this package for my purpose.

What I was thinking about is to use the FDataGrid to set as follows:

```
-> gridpoints = [t1, ..., tm]
where all the tm vectors are of length T (the temporal vector of each log file)

                [f11, ..., fn1]
-> datamatrix = [f12, ..., fn2]
                [..., ..., ...]
                [f1m, ..., fnm]
where all the fnm are vectors of length T corrensponding to the m-th observation of the n-th signal.
```

The constructor skfda.FDataGrid returns an error due to the dimension mismatch.

This is my example code:

```
obs1_var1 = np.ones(100,dtype=int)
obs2_var1 = np.ones(100,dtype=int)*2
obs1_var2 = np.ones(100,dtype=int)*3
obs2_var2 = np.ones(100,dtype=int)*4
t = np.linspace(0, 100, num=100, dtype=int)

grid_points_target = [t, t]
data_matrix_target = [[obs1_var1,obs2_var1],
[obs1_var2,obs2_var2]]
dg_target = skfda.FDataGrid(data_matrix_target, 
grid_points_target)

ValueError: Incorrect dimension in data_matrix and grid_points. Data has shape (2, 100) and grid points have shape [100,100]
```

Two variables with two observations and same time vector applied to both the variables.

Is there a way to handle this kind of dataset? I didn't find anything similar online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want:

```py
obs1_var1 = np.ones(100,dtype=int)
obs2_var1 = np.ones(100,dtype=int)*2
obs1_var2 = np.ones(100,dtype=int)*3
obs2_var2 = np.ones(100,dtype=int)*4
t = np.linspace(0, 100, num=100, dtype=int)

grid_points_target = [t]
data_matrix_target = np.array([
    np.array([obs1_var1,obs2_var1]).T,
    np.array([obs1_var2,obs2_var2]).T,
])
dg_target = skfda.FDataGrid(data_matrix_target, grid_points_target)
```

Here the dataset consist on two constant, vector-valued functions: f1(t) = (1, 2) and f2(t) = (3, 4). As I said, I am not sure if this is what you wanted but I hope that it is useful.

Additional notes:

- scikit-fda is not officially related with scikit-learn (but we try to be compatible with them). Thus, the scikit-learn tag is misleading.
- As there is no scikit-fda tag, I recommend that questions are made in the repo "Discussions" tab (https://github.com/GAA-UAM/scikit-fda/discussions) so that the developers and users that have notifications enabled can answer more quickly.

Disclaimer: I am the main maintainer of scikit-fda.

Comment: Your solution is what I asked for. Thank you. I take the opportunity to ask another question considering that you are the maintainer: is it possible to run FPCA with this kind of dataset considering all the samples for all the functions?

Comment: Unfortunately, FPCA does not yet support vector-valued functions. In general, in scikit-fda we are focusing in having good support for univariate scalar-valued functions first. However, we take into account user problems when looking at future improvements of the library, so I suggest you to create an issue for that.